# Application crash with memory warnings when NSLog enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode6

My application is frequently receiving memory warnings and crashes with I enable NSLog statements and run it via XCode 6.1. It works fine in release mode by disabling NSLog statements. I am not able to memory profile the app using instruments as even instrument hangs when I run with NSLog statements enabled.

Has anyone faced this issue and know of a workaround?

This is how I am defining a macro to enable logs when running in DEBUG mode.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define MYLOG(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
```

....

```
MYLOG(@"Log something");
```

Comment: Perhaps your `NSLog` statements log large objects or cause reference cycles.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy How can NSLog cause reference (retain) cycle?

Comment: It's unlikely but perhaps it could depending on how the logging is done or the objects's `description` method is implemented.

Comment: It's most likely WHAT you're logging and not the fact that you're logging it.  Accessing any property can actually run some getter code and do virtually anything.  So you have to track it down and see what's really happening when you access that property to NSLog it out.

Comment: @rmaddy: Thank you for all your suggestions. Found the issue. Strangely it was not because of NSLog. Posted my answer in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. It was not NSLog. Application was crashing in Debug mode only and it was because NSZombie was enabled. Once I disabled NSZombie, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following and It works fine for me.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define MYLOG(format, ...) NSLog(format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define MYLOG(...)
#endif
```